# IntelliJ + Perforce Automatically Ignores New Files

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce, p4v

When I add a new (`.java`) file to my project in IntelliJ, it does not get automatically added to p4, even though it was configured to do it.

When I try to add it manually to p4 (using p4v -> rclick -> add) it says "ignored file can't be added". I have not done anything to mark this file as "ignored". I have also checked the `.p4ignore` file in my p4 client root dir. It does not have any rules targeting that directory or `*.java`.

I can go to command line and do `p4 reconcile -I`, which has the effect of adding the file to p4. But why do I need to do this? Why don't new files get added to p4 automatically, and why does p4 see them as "ignored"?

I am using IntelliJ 13.1.1 Ultimate on Win7 64-bit with the P4 plugin. Using p4v version "2013-09-24". IntelliJ is configured to silently add new files to p4 (File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Confirmation). The IntelliJ-specific list of ignored files contains only IntelliJ-specific files (`*.iws`, `.idea/`, etc.).

Comment: I'd suggest you file an issue to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ and attach your log (Help | SHow log), p4.output (Settings | Version Control | Perforce | Dump...) and a couple screenshots there.

Comment: Also, make sure you check the entire tree from your p4 root all the way down to the directory containing the `.java` files.   Perforce walks up the tree from the directory containing the file to be checked in all the way to the root when evaluating `.p4ignores`.

Comment: The Idea log has no exceptions related to the these operations. The p4.output contains:
17:54:06 add -f -n C:\dev\...\tests\WhyIsItIgnored.java
//BMC/main/src/.../tests/WhyIsItIgnored.java#1 - opened for add
C:\dev\...\tests\WhyIsItIgnored.java - ignored file can't be added.
17:54:06 have C:/dev/p4/bmc/src/.../tests/WhyIsItIgnored.java
C:/dev/p4/bmc/src/.../tests/WhyIsItIgnored.java - file(s) not on client.
17:54:06 add -f -n C:\dev\...\tests\WhyIsItIgnored.java
//BMC/main/src/.../tests/WhyIsItIgnored.java#1 - opened for add
C:\dev\...\tests\WhyIsItIgnored.java - ignored file can't be added.

Comment: @gaige Good suggestions. I have opened a ticket with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery solved. I was adding files with the pattern `a\b\c\test\d\e\Fgh.java`.
There was no directive to ignore `*.java`. but there was an instruction to ignore `test\*`. There were no additional p4Ignore files up and down the tree, though it's a good suggestion to check for such things.
Works as designed. No issue to report.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple P4IGNORE files in your client workspace, not just the one in the client's root directory. The Perforce client-side software will search the directory containing the file to be added, its parent directory, and so forth, looking for P4IGNORE files which control the file ignoring behaviors.

See: http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore